# Помогите найти нужный инструмент

Tags: windows, css3, html5, xubuntu

я начинающий в вёрстке. Решили с товарищем сделать какой-нибудь проект (шаблон сайта) вместе. Подскажите пожалуйста несколько платформ / инструментов / облак (если дадите совет как можно лучше организоваться, буду благодарен), для кооперативной работы в режиме онлайн или так, что бы могли постоянно раздельно заходить и вносить поправки, спасибо.

Comment: Смотри по запросу git и github ( опционально gitlab, bitbucket)

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы ищите называется VCS - Version Control System, система управления версиями. Такие системы позволяют создавать централизованные, а в наше время чаще децентрализованные хранилища кода и управлять вносимыми в код правками, объединяя правки от разных разработчиков, ведя лог всех изменений, помогая вести несколько параллельных версий продукта.

Самая популярная система контроля версий  сегодня это git 
https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/ - здесь вы найдет исчерпывающую информацию об этой VCS

Однако лично я предпочитаю Mercurial, по мне она проще и удобнее чем гит, хотя и менее популярна. 
https://hgbook.bacher09.org/html-single/ - здесь вы найдете все про эту VCS

Comment: Правильно VCS - Version Control System. CVS (Concurrent Versions System) - это одна из существующих VCS.

Comment: да, вы правы. исправил ответ

Comment: А нет, скажем, текстового редактора , что бы онлайн можно было писать код ? 
Мы изначально рассматривали  https://codepen.io , может есть что-то лучше ? 
Git полезно, спасибо, обратим внимание.

Comment: @Loney_Space к примеру [Cloud9](https://c9.io/login) , но всё равно нужна будет система контроля версий для командной работы. Без VCS цена ошибки велика